# Haproxy redirect same url with different path to different backend port

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I want to redirect a URL with two different paths to two different port on a backend server.

So for example i have the url:

`https://testmysite.com/app1/*` ------> redirects to backend port xxx

`https://testmysite.com/app1/app2/*` -------> redirects to same backend port yyy

here's how i've tried doing it:

```
    acl is_test-app hdr_end(host) -i testmysite.com
    acl is_test-app1 path_beg /app1/*
    acl is_test-app2 path_beg /app1/app2/*

    use_backend server1:xxx if is_test-app is_test-app1
    use_backend server1:yyy if is_test-app is_test-app2
```

I've tried looking at other similar questions but all are a bit different from mine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two different backend groups (might have one server each, with ports you want).
Then use that backend in the use_backend instruction.